# how to set variable value in query function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

1.here i need "did" value outside if condition but when it's going in IF and execute query than it's not setting up the value of did which I define in function "did = doc.value.seqValue" getting undefined.
2. else working fine.

```
var did;
if (documents[0] == null) {
           
           dbo
             .collection("Domain")
             .findOneAndUpdate(
               { _id: "Did" },
               { $inc: { seqValue: 1 } },
               function (err, doc) {
                 if (err) throw err;
                 
                 dbo.collection("Domain").insertOne(
                   {
                     _id: doc.value.seqValue,
                     UserID: parseInt(req.body.userid),
                     ClientID: parseInt(req.body.clientid),
                     Domain: req.body.domain,
                     IsDeleted: false,
                     CreatedBy: parseInt(createdby),
                     CreatedDate: new Date(),
                     LastUpdatedDate: null,
                     LastUpdatedBy: null,
                   },

                   function (err, data) {
                     if (err) throw err;
                     did = doc.value.seqValue;
                    
                   }
                 );
               }
             );
         } else {

           did = documents[0].DomainID;
         }
```

Comment: Does the code wait for the findOneAndUpdate callback to resolve?

Comment: Yes but outside if  else i am calling one more query there I didn't getting did value

Comment: That's what I mean.  FindOneAndUpdate returns immediately, so the code immediately following the if-else will be executed long before the query completes and the callback is executed.

Comment: if i am putting did = doc.value.seqValue in FindOneAndUpdate still i don't getting vlaue!